# Custom Hibernate Validator Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I wish to use the [Java 8 ReflectionParameterNameProvider](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-parameter-name-provider) Hibernate Validator to return proper parameter names instead of **.argN** e.g. `getPerson.arg0`

I am compiling the application with the -parameter flag and have added the following Bean to my context:

```
@Bean
public javax.validation.Validator validator() {
    ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.byDefaultProvider()
        .configure()
        .parameterNameProvider(new ReflectionParameterNameProvider())
        .buildValidatorFactory();

    return validatorFactory.getValidator();
}
```

But am still getting the old `getPerson.arg0`

Any ideas, Thanks?

Answer (score 1):

If you are relying on Hibernate Validator's integration with Hibernate to perform the validation, I found that it was necessary to put all my configuration inside `validation.xml` and let Hibernate Validator bootstrap from that configuration instead.

The configuration you've specified will work for spring-specific things, but won't work for the Hibernate/Hibernate Validator integration unfortunately.

Comment: It seems to suggest you can do either in the documentation "To use ReflectionParameterNameProvider or another custom provider either pass an instance of the provider during bootstrapping as shown in Example 8.8, “Using a custom ParameterNameProvider”, or specify the fully qualified class name of the provider as value for the <parameter-name-provider> element in the META-INF/validation.xml file"

Comment: That was what I thought but not what I observed recently in an exercise of my own.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, just had to set this in the methodValidationPostProcessor bean.

```
import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.validation.ValidatorFactory;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor;


@Bean
public Validator validator() {
    final ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.byDefaultProvider()
            .configure()
            .parameterNameProvider(new ReflectionParameterNameProvider())
            .buildValidatorFactory();
    return validatorFactory.getValidator();
}

@Bean
public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
    final MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor = new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
    methodValidationPostProcessor.setValidator(validator());
    return methodValidationPostProcessor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, that also keeps all Spring defaults untouched, is to override method [`postProcessConfiguration()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/LocalValidatorFactoryBean.html#postProcessConfiguration-javax.validation.Configuration-):

```
@Bean
static LocalValidatorFactoryBean defaultValidator() {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean() {

        @Override
        protected void postProcessConfiguration(
            javax.validation.Configuration<?> configuration) {
            configuration.parameterNameProvider(new ReflectionParameterNameProvider());
        }
    };
    MessageInterpolatorFactory interpolatorFactory = new MessageInterpolatorFactory();
    factoryBean.setMessageInterpolator(interpolatorFactory.getObject());
    return factoryBean;
}
```